# I want to store a value in a variable in a dynamic query then want to run another query on checking of this variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to use the i_count variable in later section of my procedure but the value does not getting assigned.

Again when I use general query not the dynamic one at front then its running perfect anyway.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `common2`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `common2`(tablename VARCHAR(50),attr_name VARCHAR(50),pk BIGINT(255),i_block_id BIGINT(255))
BEGIN
DECLARE i_count INTEGER(255);

set @sql_text = concat('SELECT COUNT(',pk,') INTO  @i_count FROM ',tablename, ' WHERE ',attr_name,'=1 AND ',pk,'=',i_block_id);

prepare statement from @sql_text;


    execute statement;
#deallocate prepare statement; 

IF (i_count=1) THEN
set @sql_text1 = concat('UPDATE ',tablename, '  SET ',attr_name,'=0 WHERE ',attr_name,'=1 AND ',pk,'=',i_block_id);
prepare statement1 from @sql_text1;
    execute statement1;
#deallocate prepare statement; 
   ELSE
set @sql_text2 = concat('UPDATE ',tablename, ' SET ',attr_name,'=1 WHERE ',attr_name,'=0 AND ',pk,'=',i_block_id);
prepare statement2 from @sql_text2;
    execute statement2;
#deallocate prepare statement; 

   END IF;




END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between these two variables. Variables starting with @ are [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). Variables that are declared are [local variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-local-variable.html).

Write it like this:

```
delimiter $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `common2`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `common2`(tablename VARCHAR(50),attr_name VARCHAR(50),pk BIGINT(255),i_block_id BIGINT(255))
BEGIN

set @i_count = 0;

set @sql_text = concat('SELECT COUNT(',pk,') INTO  @i_count FROM ',tablename, ' WHERE ',attr_name,'=1 AND ',pk,'=',i_block_id);

prepare statement from @sql_text;


    execute statement;
#deallocate prepare statement; 

IF (@i_count=1) THEN
set @sql_text1 = concat('UPDATE ',tablename, '  SET ',attr_name,'=0 WHERE ',attr_name,'=1 AND ',pk,'=',i_block_id);
prepare statement1 from @sql_text1;
    execute statement1;
#deallocate prepare statement; 
   ELSE
set @sql_text2 = concat('UPDATE ',tablename, ' SET ',attr_name,'=1 WHERE ',attr_name,'=0 AND ',pk,'=',i_block_id);
prepare statement2 from @sql_text2;
    execute statement2;
#deallocate prepare statement; 

   END IF;

END $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Its giving error , already tried error is undeclared variable i_count

Comment: Well, but you're declaring the variable at the very beginning. Are you sure there's no mismatch between the code you posted here and the one you execute?

Comment: Yes very much sure about that !

Comment: set @sql_text2 = concat('UPDATE ',tablename, ' SET ',attr_name,'=1 WHERE ',attr_name,'=0 AND ',pk,'=',i_block_id);
prepare statement2 from @sql_text;
    execute statement2; this was bit mistaken I guess , I fixed that but still does not affecting any rows ! sorry to bother you again and again

Comment: in your last prepared statement you probably want to write `prepare statement2 from @sql_text2;`, not `prepare statement2 from @sql_text;`.

Comment: But its not working anyway ! can you give more into it please :)

Comment: :) You need to give more info, not me. I know my code is working and I even did a small test with the above and it's working for me.

Comment: The query should affect 1 row atleast each time it runs but it is not doing that . For this reason I am saying this is not working ! I hope I have have to make my point clear .

Comment: You made your point clear, yes. But you have to give more information why. Based on the information given, how should anyone know? All I can say is, that an update query usually updates, except when you want to update although the value doesn't actually change. Then MySQL spares itself the trouble.